# unsure how to unwrap uilabel optional to calculate my to uilabels

Tags: swift

I am new in the developer world and have been on and off since february with swift and Xcode. I am hoping someone could help me out. Im trying to make a simple tip calculator and can't  seem to * two uilabels together. this is what i have so far... at the total.text = "(totalAmount) * (tipPercent)" ... thanks any help would be great. :)

```
@IBOutlet weak var totalAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textFIeld: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tipPercent: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var slider: UISlider!
@IBOutlet weak var total: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var tip: UILabel!


@IBAction func sliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
    sldr()

    total.text = "\(totalAmount) * \(tipPercent)"
}


@IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    ttl()
}

func ttl() {
    if let grandTotal = textFIeld.text {
        totalAmount.text! = "\(grandTotal)"
    }
}

func sldr() {
    tipPercent.text! = "\(Int(slider.value))"
}
```

Comment: Don't use labels to hold your data. Only use the labels to display your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below expression will just only return you a string without any multiplication that you are expecting.

```
total.text = "\(totalAmount) * \(tipPercent)"
```

You know how to unwrap the text as you have done in `ttl`. You should use the same approach here

```
if let totalTxt = totalAmount.text, let percentTxt = tipPercent.text {
      //Then change to whatever scalar type you want
      if let totalAmount = Float(totalTxt), let percent = Float(percentTxt) {
          let totalBill = totalAmount * percent
          total.text = "\(totalBill)"
      }
 }
```

Comment: That actually did it, thanks for the quick response :) although i made a mistake with the calculation because i basically put bill amount * 15 instead of 1.15 to get the total including tip. Thanks again!